# Configure UnboundedControlAwareMailbox

Tags: java, akka

I am attempting to use an UnboundedControlAwareMailbox in Akka 2.4.0.

I have created an actor implementing `RequiresMessageQueue<UnboundedControlAwareMessageQueueSemantics>`:

```
public class ControlActor extends AbstractLoggingActor
    implements RequiresMessageQueue<UnboundedControlAwareMailbox> {
    public ControlActor(ActorRef testActor) {
        this.testActor = testActor;
        receive(ReceiveBuilder.
                    match(HiPriority.class,
                          msg -> testActor.tell(msg, self())).
                    match(LoPriority.class,
                          msg -> testActor.tell(msg, self())).
                    build());
    }

    private void forward(Object msg) {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);
            testActor.tell(msg, self());
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            log().error(exc, "Failed to wait or forward");
            fail(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private final ActorRef testActor;
}
```

to use these messages:

```
public class HiPriority implements ControlMessage {
    String id;
}

public class LoPriority {
    String id;
}
```

[The mailbox documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/mailboxes.html) suggests that I can create the actor by

```
system.actorOf(Props.create(ControlActor.class,
                            getRef()).
                   withDispatcher("akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-control-aware-queue-based").
               "control");
```

but even

```
system.actorOf(Props.create(ControlActor.class,
                            getRef()).                                                      
                    withDispatcher("akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-control-aware-queue-based").
                    withMailbox("akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-control-aware-queue-based"),
               "control");
```

fails with

```
akka.ConfigurationException: configuration problem while creating [akka://ControlActorTest/user/control] with dispatcher [akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-control-aware-queue-based] and mailbox [akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-control-aware-queue-based]
at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.actorOf(ActorRefProvider.scala:766) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:220) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.attachChild(Children.scala:42) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.attachChild(ActorCell.scala:373) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.actorOf(ActorSystem.scala:586) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: produced message queue type [class akka.dispatch.UnboundedControlAwareMailbox$MessageQueue] does not fulfill requirement for actor class [class com.str.rspace.ControlActorTest$ControlActor]
at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.verifyRequirements$1(Mailboxes.scala:141) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.getMailboxType(Mailboxes.scala:147) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.actorOf(ActorRefProvider.scala:761) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
... 34 common frames omitted
```

The examples do use UntypedActor.  Is there a different way to do this using the AbstractActor classes?

If not, how do I configure my actor to use this queue semantics?

**Use Case**

When I wrote this, I was just trying to have an actor that received two types of messages, and would process all of the first type that had been received before processing any of the second type.  Basically, the control messages (first type) configured the current environment and the second type of messages requested solving a problem in the current environment.  After a solve, the environment needed to be updated to reflect the solution, so if two solve messages were received, after processing the first solve, I need to receive and process a control message to reflect that solution before processing the second solve message.

This seems like a straight forward use of the ControlAware semantics/mailbox/dispatcher, but I was not able to start my actor with that option.

To ensure that I could receive the control message after the first solve and before the second solve was processed, the actor is a FSM actor.  The actor stashes messages when it is not in the right state, which allows a second actor to send the control message after the first solve.  So at this point, I need  both stashing and control messages.  Stashing requires deque semantics.  High-priority messages require control-aware semantics.  I found dispatchers that use each individually, but I did not find one that uses both.

I ended up implementing a custom mailbox that uses two DequeBasedMessageQueue to gain all of the functionality that I needed.

I will try to upgrade to Akka 2.5 soon, but we are currently doing integration testing and I do not want to make such a change until that is over.

Comment: Could you please upgrade to a more recent version of Akka? We've started producing a more useful error message since version 2.4.1, but it might be worth it to upgrade all the way to 2.5.9. This should be relatively painless because Akka is binary compatible within the whole 2.x.x series (except for API's that have been marked as such)

Comment: Also it might be useful to share why you are creating such a setup: in most common use cases it is rarely needed to perform such deep customizations, and the default mailboxes should be fine.